# ColorBlob detection in an imageview in android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

Assume that I have an image like this,[image]

I want to draw contours around the roof and the wall. It may be achieved by color blob detection. There is a sample provided in Opencv 3.10, but its for camera view. I want it in an android imageView. Is there any way to achieve this?

Tried this code:

```
         File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/instahome/" + imgName);

        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.d("heree",imgFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
            mRgba = new Mat(myBitmap.getHeight(), myBitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
            ivw.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            try {
                detectEdges(myBitmap);
               // contours(myBitmap);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Error!!!", e.toString());
            }
        }
        ivw.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int cols = mRgba.cols();
                int rows = mRgba.rows();

                int xOffset = (ivw.getWidth() - cols) / 2;
                int yOffset = (ivw.getHeight() - rows) / 2;

                int x = (int)event.getX() - xOffset;
                int y = (int)event.getY() - yOffset;

                Log.d(TAG, "Touch image coordinates: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");

                if ((x < 0) || (y < 0) || (x > cols) || (y > rows)) return false;

                Rect touchedRect = new Rect();

                touchedRect.x = (x>4) ? x-4 : 0;
                touchedRect.y = (y>4) ? y-4 : 0;

                touchedRect.width = (x+4 < cols) ? x + 4 - touchedRect.x : cols - touchedRect.x;
                touchedRect.height = (y+4 < rows) ? y + 4 - touchedRect.y : rows - touchedRect.y;

                Mat touchedRegionRgba = mRgba.submat(touchedRect);

                Mat touchedRegionHsv = new Mat();
                Imgproc.cvtColor(touchedRegionRgba, touchedRegionHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);

                // Calculate average color of touched region
                mBlobColorHsv = Core.sumElems(touchedRegionHsv);
               int pointCount = touchedRect.width*touchedRect.height;
                for (int i = 0; i < mBlobColorHsv.val.length; i++)
                    mBlobColorHsv.val[i] /= pointCount;

                mBlobColorRgba = converScalarHsv2Rgba(mBlobColorHsv);

                Log.d(TAG, "Touched rgba color: (" + mBlobColorRgba.val[0] + ", " + mBlobColorRgba.val[1] +
                        ", " + mBlobColorRgba.val[2] + ", " + mBlobColorRgba.val[3] + ")");

                mDetector.setHsvColor(mBlobColorHsv);

                Imgproc.resize(mDetector.getSpectrum(), mSpectrum, SPECTRUM_SIZE);

                mIsColorSelected = true;
                if (mIsColorSelected) {
                    mRgba= new Mat(myBitmap.getHeight(), myBitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
                    mDetector.process(mRgba);
                    List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Contours count: " + contours.size());
                    Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR);

                    Mat colorLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 68, 4, 68);
                    colorLabel.setTo(mBlobColorRgba);

                    Mat spectrumLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 4 + mSpectrum.rows(), 70, 70 + mSpectrum.cols());
                    mSpectrum.copyTo(spectrumLabel);
                    Bitmap newBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(),myBitmap.getHeight(),myBitmap.getConfig());
                    try {
                    Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba,newBitmap);

                }catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.d("error!", ex.toString());
                    }
                    ivw.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
                }
                touchedRegionRgba.release();
                touchedRegionHsv.release();

                return false; // don't need subsequent touch events
            }

        });

        addListeners();
        addViews();


    }
```

Searching around 5-6 hours, but no luck, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried, besides searching?

Comment: @Dan updated question. But after clicking, image disappears!

Comment: Much better :) I'm not an Android dev, but perhaps you have to [`invalidate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) the view after you `setImageBitmap` in the `onTouch` handler?